# Jenkins declarative pipline multiple slave

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have a pipeline with multiple stages, some of them are in parallel. Up until now I had a single code block indicating where the job should run.

```
pipeline {
 triggers { pollSCM '0 0 * * 0' } 
 agent { dockerfile { label 'jenkins-slave'
                      filename 'Dockerfile'
                    }
       }
 stages{ 
  stage('1'){ 
   steps{ sh "blah" }
   } // stage
  } // stages
} // pipeline
```

What I need to do now is run a new stage on a different slave, NOT in docker.

I tried by adding an agent statement for that stage but it seems like it tries to run that stage withing a docker container on the second slave.

```
    stage('test new slave') {
     agent { node { label 'e2e-aws' } }
     steps {
      sh "ifconfig"
     } // steps
    } // stage
```

I get the following error message
13:14:23 unknown flag: --workdir
13:14:23 See 'docker exec --help'.

I tried setting the agent to none for the pipeline and using an agent for every step and have run into 2 issues
1. My post actions show an error
2. The stages that have parallel stages also had an error.

I can't find any examples that are similar to what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the node block to select a node to run a particular stage.

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Init') {
        steps {
            node('master'){
                echo "Run inside a MASTER"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried, it tries to run that stage also in docker even though it has no docker or dockerfile directive.

Comment: Could you please share the log of the pipeline that I shared above?